# A one-liner to read null-split lines into an array?

Tags: bash

Here is how to split a `tab`-split line into an array:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -a array < <(echo -e "a\tb\tc")
```

And here is how to read `null`-terminated lines into an array:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' item
do array+=("$item")
done < <(echo -e "a\0b\0c\0")
```

Now, is it possible to combine both and have a **one-liner** suitable to read a `null`-split line into an array?

---

First, putting `-r -d ''`  together with `-a array`, and setting `IFS` to empty, doesn't to work:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -a array < <(echo -e "a\0b\0c")
```

as `array` will have 1 item: `a`

---

Secondly, such `while` construct reading a `null`-split line into an array is mildly unsatisfactory. It will **drop** the last item if the last item isn't followed by `null`. A workaround is to append the last item to the array **after** the loop, as suggested by chepner below.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' item
do array+=("$item")
done < <(echo -e "a\0b\0c")
array+=("$item")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't, if you don't consider a single while loop a "one"-liner.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do array+=("$item"); done < <(echo -e "a\0b\0c\0")
```

`read` only reads a line of input at a time, and you are using `-d ''` to define what a line is. That is, you aren't treating "a\0b\0c" as a single line of input, but as multiple lines separate by null byte. The `readarray` command, introduced in `bash` 4, doesn't provide a way to specify what to consider as the line separator.

Comment: Too bad. It seems the `while` construct drops any last item lacking a `\0` at the end.  Try it: `while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do array+=("$item"); done < <(echo -e "a\0b\0c"); echo "${array[@]}"`

Comment: Almost. `read` does have a nonzero exit status in that case, terminating the loop in that case. However, `item` is still updated to contain the last bit of text, so you can update the array after the loop.

Comment: @accuya `read` requires the string it reads from to end with the expected delimiter, or it has an non-zero exit status. This would prevent the body from executing, meaning the last element of the input would not be added to `array`.

Comment: Note that in `bash` 4.4, `readarray` received the same `-d` option that `read` has, although in limited testing I see what appears to be a bug regarding the treatment of the final element. I haven't looked closely enough to determine if my test is bad, or if a bug report is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

`readarray` a.k.a. `mapfile` supports nul termination with the `-d ''` flag, at least in bash 5.2.2 where I tested, and 4.4.20 on a test Ubuntu 18.04 container, which is as far back as I cared to go.

## TL;DR:

```
mapfile -d '' ARRAYNAME < <(command that emits null bytes here)

mapfile -d '' ARRAYNAME < file-with-null-bytes
```

Order is significant, arrayname must come after the `-d ''`. Using a pipe instead will not work how you expect, because the `mapfile` will run in a subshell, hence the use of command-redirection above.

To append to an existing array, use

```
mapfile -d '' -O "${#ARR[@]}" ARR
```

## Demo and explanation

Set up a NUL-terminated stream with one plain entry, one entry with embedded space, and one entry with embedded newline. Use `xargs -0` to show it's correct.

```
$ python3 -c 'print("\x00".join(["1", "2 3", "4\n5"]), end="\x00")'
12 34
5
$ python3 -c 'print("\x00".join(["1", "2 3", "4\n5"]), end="\x00")' \
    | xargs -0 -I{} echo "[{}]"
[1]
[2 3]
[4
5]
```

*Python is only used to generate the demo input; use whatever else you prefer*.

Now we use `mapfile -d ''` to read the demo null terminated stream and verify that it was split solely on null bytes:

```
$ mapfile -d '' ARR < <(python3 -c 'print("\x00".join(["1", "2 3", "4\n5"]), end="\x00")')
$ echo "${#ARR[@]}"
3
$ printf "[%s]" "${ARR[@]}"
[1][2 3][4
5]$
```

Note:

- `readarray` is just an alias for `mapfile`
- You can write `mapfile -d $'\0' ARRAYNAME` instead if you want, to make your intent more explicit. `$'xxxxx'` is  a bash escape-string. But bash strings are null-terminated, so `$'\0'` is the same as the empty-string anyway. `mapfile` special-cases the zero-length delimiter argument to mean null terminated.
- Order of arguments to `mapfile` is significant. Array name must be the last argument. `mapfile ARRAYNAME -d ''` is not the same as `mapfile -d '' ARRAYNAME`. Redirection operators are removed by the calling shell so they don't count.
- Invoking `mapfile` in a pipeline won't export the resulting array to the shell that invokes the pipeline, because the `mapfile` in the pipeline will run in its own separate shell process. Use *process substitution redirection* `< <(command)` instead of a pipe.

  So this *won't work*

  ```
  $ # DELIBERATELY WRONG #
  $ python3 -c 'print("\x00".join(["1", "2 3", "4\n5"]), end="\x00")' | mapfile -d '' ARR2
  $ echo "${#ARR2[@]}"
  0
  $ echo "${ARR2[@]}"  

  $ # DELIBERATELY WRONG #
  ```

---

I used Python for the demo output because working with null bytes in bash is too painful. Here's an alternative using only sh etc, using the creation of files and then `find -print0` to get the desired output:

```
mkdir omg
cd omg
touch '1' '2 3' $'4\n5'
find . -print0
```